# YouTube keeps crashing on iPad Pro 13 inch

Tags: ipad

I tried to watch unbox therapy’s new video: “The Worst Text You Could Ever Recieve” and the YouTube app keeps quitting. Furthermore, my screen just blacks out for a second before showing the home screen. This is only for one video, not others. Tried restarting, no effect. Running latest version of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about of symbol that is killing ios devices. I think they have added it in the description. Symbol instantly kills ios app that tried to open it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.